# Method setAttribute not working all the time

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a code that when on hover, some text is displayed on a div at the top of the page depending on the selected Option.

When I change the Option the text displayed on hover works just sometimes.

I'm pulling the information from a SVG , and that is the information I'm changing.

This is one of the values from the SVG:

```
<path id="HI" data-info="<div>State: Hawaii</div><div>Capital: 
  Honolulu</div>"
```

I'm changing it with this:

```
document.getElementById('HI').setAttribute('data-info','State: Alabama  
 </br> Owner: xyz ');
```

And this method is called inside a .change(function()) so when I change the Option it updates the info.

And this is my hover function

```
 $("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
 $('#info-box').css('display','inline');
 $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
  });
```

Again, this works just sometimes, so I'm not really sure why the info does not get updated all the time.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Can you give an example of a path that isn't working?

Comment: Need to the SVG and HTML. First, we can't assume that you targeted the correct tag hence we need HTML. Secondly, there's usually a ton of critical info an SVG has that could enlighten us.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, and using [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function, then why not also use it to set the value as well as read?

`$(this).data('info', 'State: Alabama </br> Owner: xyz');`